# Dynamically show enum values based on the class that implements them

Tags: java, enums

I'm building a JavaFx application.
I want to dynamically show enum values in different comboboxes.

For example, in controller A I only want to show enum value "high" and in controller B I want to show all enum values.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
public enum EnumPrio {

    High("high"),
    Medium("medium"),
    Low("low");

    private String prio;

    EnumPrio(String prio) {
        this.prio = prio;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's the controllers job to select what part of the model to want to view, and how. you may add some methods to the enum to conveniently get the data formatted the way you want. particularly with the example you give it's the difference between displaying 1 thing and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum EnumPrio {

    High("high"),
    Medium("medium"),
    Low("low");

    private String prio;

    EnumPrio(String prio) {
        this.prio = prio;
    }

    public static List<EnumPrio> getEnumPrioListByController(String controller) {
        Stream<EnumPrio> enumPrioStream=Stream.of(EnumPrio.values());

        return controller.equals("A")?enumPrioStream
                .filter(enumPrio->enumPrio.prio.equals("high")).collect(Collectors.toList()):enumPrioStream
                .filter(enumPrio->!enumPrio.prio.equals("high")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("enumPrioListForControllerA="+EnumPrio.getEnumPrioListByController("A"));
        // enumPrioListForControllerA=[High]
        System.out.println("enumPrioListForControllerB="+EnumPrio.getEnumPrioListByController("B"));
        // enumPrioListForControllerB=[Medium, Low]
    }
}
```